# Brand new alternator: only 2 Volts

Tags: alternator, suzuki, voltage, swift

I just installed a brand new alternator in my car. The output voltage is just above 2V regardless of engine RPM. The exciter voltage from the battery is A-OK. The previous alternator had the same problem. I can not stress enough that neither alternators could generate more than 3V since this problem emerged. Thus the cause should be something else. Any ideas?
Suzuki Swift 2003

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure on the Swift, but your alternator may be regulated through the ECU. If so, it could be your ECU which is causing the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bad ground for it or a poor connection in the wiring.

Comment: I second possible main engine ground issue. A well known YouTube repair shop was the second choice after a dealer replaced parts at around $1200. Problem returned. This repair shop videoed most of his diagnosing/troubleshooting, found a severely corroded engine ground strap. Electric pwr steering, electrical problems, you name it - the dealer unable to determine the problem but happily billed the owner for a poorly serviced vehicle. As soon as the engine ground strap was replaced with a 4 or 2 gauge insulated ground cable, every problem disappeared. Dealer reimbursed owner (video shaming?)

Comment: Thank you very much for all responses, I will thoroughly examine all connections and check the grounding as well

Comment: How are you testing the voltage?  Have you disconnected the alternator from the battery?